# angular routes, not getting a # after index.html

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am trying to set up a SPA with angular, and with the current code it is not working, while run on a server. My index.html does not have a # after it, which I think it should for the SPA. I am curious why I am not getting a # in the url's. for example, navigating to the index i get something like localhost:4000/index.html/ instead of localhost:4000/index.html#/. When i try to navigate to localhost:4000/index.html/home i get a 404 error. Can anyone tell me why this is so, or if there are any other issues you can spot.

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ski</title>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="Ski">

<ng-view></ng-view>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/routes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

angular routes :

```
angular.module('Ski').config(function($routeProvider) {
  'use strict';
  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
  })
  .when('/map', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/map.html'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

app.js

```
angular.module('Ski', ['ngRoute']);
```

Templates: 
this on is templates/maps

```
<div>
  <h1> Hello World </h1>
</div>
```

this one is templates/home

```
<h1> Home </h1>
```

Comment: Anything in your console? Also, why is your code not in a <script> tag?

Comment: no errors in the console. Also each code block is in a separate file, html or js where needed.  i just edited it, sorry for the confusion

Comment: The `.when` doesn't appear to be attached to anything. Was that a typo?

Comment: yes i needed to attache the when to a $routeProvider. Thanks for the help.